# Updating a Label widget in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a Label on Kivy defined in KV like this:

```
Label:
    id: vol
    text: '[color=#3333ff]Volume: {0:8.2f}[/color]'
    markup: True
    size_hint_x: 0.2
```

Every few seconds, I update it with code that look like this:

```
self.vol.text = self.vol.text.format(tick['volume'])
```

However the text does not get updated on the app, staying as I first set it.

What is required to have the Label be redrawn after I change its text content?

Answer (score 1):

Once the first replacement has taken place, there is no replacement field left to take the updated value. Instead, try something like this:

```
self.vol.text = '[color=#3333ff]Volume: {0:8.2f}[/color]'.format(tick['volume'])
```

If you want, you can subclass `Label` and add a custom update function, so that knowledge about the formatting string resides with the label, and the update function can be called from different places.